# I want to show 0 if no record found for a particular date

Tags: mysql

In mysql I have created a query where I want to get last one month data for each date, and if no record found for a particular date then it should show 0.

My mysql query is

> select  SUM(testviewaudit.action=1)  AS view,
>   DATE(testviewaudit.datetime) from testviewaudit inner join tmtests on 
>   testviewaudit.testid=tmtests.tsid  where DATE(testviewaudit.datetime)
>   BETWEEN NOW() -  INTERVAL 30 DAY AND  NOW() group by 
>   DATE(testviewaudit.datetime) order by  DATE(testviewaudit.datetime)
>   asc;

well I have used this also but no success

> select  ifnull(SUM(testviewaudit.action=1), 0)  AS view,
>   DATE(testviewaudit.datetime) from testviewaudit inner join tmtests on
>   testviewaudit.testid=tmtests.tsid  where DATE(testviewaudit.datetime)
>   BETWEEN NOW() -  INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() group by 
>   DATE(testviewaudit.datetime) order by DATE(testviewaudit.datetime)
>   asc;

still getting the same result

Comment: and what is "the same result" ?

Comment: i want                                                                                                   view   date                                                                                                                                                                                                           84 2016-03-30
98 2016-03-31                                                                                      0  2016-03-31 basically i want 0 if no record found

Comment: ok, to rephrase: could you please tell us what is going wrong?

Comment: Well I want 0 in view if for a particular date I have no record, but it is not displaying that date

Comment: you show nothing of what and how you display anything in your view, so ...  
you an adjust your sql query to return a default value (as the answers propose) or you can adjust the code that handles the result of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select  if(is null(testviewaudit.action), 0 , sum(testviewaudit.action=1))  AS view,
DATE(testviewaudit.datetime) from testviewaudit inner join tmtests on testviewaudit.testid=tmtests.tsid 
where DATE(testviewaudit.datetime) BETWEEN NOW() -  INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() group by  DATE(testviewaudit.datetime) order by DATE(testviewaudit.datetime) asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put the whole query in the IFNULL.

```
SELECT IFNULL( (SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE id = 1 ) ,'not found');
```

Comment: I did as said , here is my query                                                      SELECT  IFNULL( (select  sum(testviewaudit.action=1)  AS view,
      DATE(testviewaudit.datetime) from testviewaudit inner join tmtests on testviewaudit.testid=tmtests.tsid 
      where DATE(testviewaudit.datetime) BETWEEN NOW() -  INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() group by  DATE(testviewaudit.datetime) ) ,'not found');                                                   but still no record is not comming

Comment: replace 'not found' with 0